# How to change input type from password to text with toggle button of show and hide?

Tags: wordpress, laravel

I have to change the input type of a password field.
When I click on a button, it toggled from show to hide value. Also, input type changed from password to text.
How can I implement the same functionality in Laravel   as defined in WordPress -
`wordpress/wp-admin/install.php`?

Can any one help me in understanding this piece of code:

```
  <label for="pass1">
    <?php _e( 'Password' ); ?>
  </label>
  </th>
<td>
<div class="">
  <?php $initial_password = isset( $_POST['admin_password'] ) ? stripslashes( $_POST['admin_password'] ) : wp_generate_password( 18 ); ?>
```

Please, explain the below code:

```
<input type="password" name="admin_password" id="pass1" class="regular-text" autocomplete="off" data-reveal="1" data-pw="<?php echo esc_attr( $initial_password ); ?>" aria-describedby="pass-strength-result" />
<button type="button" class="button wp-hide-pw hide-if-no-js" data-start-masked="<?php echo (int) isset( $_POST['admin_password'] ); ?>" data-toggle="0" aria-label="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Hide password' ); ?>">
   <span class="dashicons dashicons-hidden"></span>
   <span class="text"><?php _e( 'Hide' ); ?></span>
</button>
```

Please, explain these terms:

```
data-reveal="1"
data-pw
aria-describedby="pass-strength-result"
data-start-masked
```

Are these HTML or Bootstrap attributes?

Please, tell me, what files are related to this code & where.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`aria-describedby` is an attribute from JavaScript.
  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/ARIA/ARIA_Techniques/Using_the_aria-describedby_attribute

`data-toggle` is an attribute from Bootstrap. [Example](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_ref_js_collapse.asp)

`aria-label` is an attribute from JavaScript. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/ARIA/ARIA_Techniques/Using_the_aria-label_attribute

`data-reveal` is an attribute from Foundation. https://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/v/5.5.3/components/reveal.html

Comment: Thanks please tell me what files like JS are included in this wordpress code so that i may able to implement in laravel

Comment: @Amir you just need to download Bootstrap and Foundation. Just google them. But still there is no guarantee that it will work. Because `data-start-masked` is an attribute from Wordpress itself and `data-pw` is unknown to me. It could be an attribute from the WP theme developer.